# Decimal Format in Jframe?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am making a pizza calculator but my results come out as "$7.5" instead of "$7.50". I have this decimal format code written out with my code below it, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
    private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

    double diameter;
    double labourCost = 1.00;

    diameter = Double.parseDouble(diameterInput.getText());

    double storeCost = 1.50;
    double materialsCost = 0.50 * diameter;
    double totalCost = labourCost + storeCost + materialsCost;

    DecimalFormat x = newDecimalFormat("0.00"); 

    costOutput.setText("The cost of the pizza is $" + totalCost);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the result ("x") of the operation for anything. I'm guessing that replacing "totalCost" with "x" in the last line will help?

Comment: it actually gave me a huge error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet."

Comment: Then something outside the code that you provided creates an error - what is the code for the newDecimalFormat, and what is the type of "costOutput"?

Comment: @JessWittman - should the line "DecimalFormat x = newDecimalFormat("0.00"); " actually create a new DecimalFormat instance? If yes, you're missing a space: "DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); ". If "newDecimalFormat" refers to a method instead, we need to see the content of that method. You should also include the type of "costOutput"

Comment: @JessWittman - you still need to include where "costOutput" is instantiated and fix the (suspected) missing whitespace, as mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Decimal Formatter to convert your floating point value over to a string.

```
// Make a new formatter with your format
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("$##.00");
// Convert your number to a human readable string
String output = myFormatter.format(22.99999f);
System.out.println(output); // Prints $23.00
```

See this page for details on the various patterns https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html